# Compatibility between Instant and ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

It is my understanding that a `ZonedDateTime` is really an enhanced version of an `Instant`. It has all the data an `Instant` has (precise value along UTC timeline), plus time zone information. So my naïve assumption was that a `ZonedDateTime` *is-an* `Instant` and that any method taking an `Instant` will happily take a `ZonedDateTime` instead. Furthermore, I expected `isBefore()`, `isAfter()` etc. to work seamlessly between `Instant`s and `ZonedDateTime`s.

Looking at the API documentation for [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/Instant.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), none of this is the case. I can compare `Instant`s with `Instant`s and `ZonedDateTime`s with `ZonedDateTime`s, but the two classes seem to be incompatible. What's more, third-party code like ThreeTen-Extra's [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html?org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) seem to work exclusively with `Instant`s.

Is there a reason why `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` are not meant to be mixed?

Comment: Well, the documentation clearly says that it should be viewed as a `LocalDateTime` coupled with a zone, note as an `Instant` coupled with a zone. It has all the date-time fields, not an offset from a point in UTC. Why do you expect it to behave other than its documentation says?

Comment: You can convert a `ZonedDateTime` to an `Instant` using [`.toInstant()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--), but to convert from an `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime`, you must use [`ZonedDateTime.ofInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) and specify a `ZoneId`.

Answer (score 10):

`Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` have different state - `Instant` is just a number of nanoseconds from the epoch, while `ZonedDateTime` consists of a `LocalDateTime`, `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`. As such, the two classes can be converted to/from each other, but are not the same (and you lose information when converting `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant`).

The behaviour of `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` matches exactly between the two however. Whereas the implementation of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) matches the recommended behaviour, which is that "It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals."  ie. `compareTo()` takes account of the local date-time, time-zone and offset, whereas `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` only consider the instant.

Writing a comparator to compare an `Instant` and a `ZonedDateTime` is relatively simple:

```
Comparator<TemporalAccessor> comparator =
    (a, b) -> Instant.from(a).compareTo(Instant.from(b));
```

which can also be written as:

```
Comparator<TemporalAccessor> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Instant::from);
```

Comment: If `Instant is just a number of nanoseconds from the epoch` why does `System.out.println(Instant.now());` output `2018-11-29T03:58:06.573Z`? It seems like an `Instance` is a number of nanoseconds together with some default Time zone to me, would you agree?

Comment: A `toString` implementation that just prints out a number of nanoseconds is not very helpful. So, the `toString` prints out the time in UTC instead.

Answer (score 7):

Because the translation is not injective. Take Sunday, October 30th 2016 2:15 AM in Germany/Munich for example: Which `Instant` does this date/time represent? This is not independently answerable without some assumptions because you don't know if this time should be translated into the `Instant` *before* or *after* the offset for daylight saving time (DST) should be applied. Or Sunday, March 27th 2016  2:15 AM in Germany/Munich: This date/time combination should not exist, as the clock should be set to 3 AM when reaching 2 AM.

Without DST the three possible cases for translating a `LocalDateTime` into an `Instant` (exact match, summertime-gap, wintertime-overlap) would be reduced to one and the conversion would be injective, AFAIK.

Edit: "Hands on" this problem, when displaying date/time in our JSF based application, we *always* pass the offset calculated accordingly to the current state of the DST into the formatter.

Comment: The ZonedDateTime docs state: "This class stores ... a zone offset used to handle ambiguous local date-times." Doesn't that mean that there is an unambiguous mapping from ZonedDateTime to Instant?

Comment: I think this answer has mixed up LocalDateTime with ZonedDateTime. The orignal question is about ZonedDateTime, but this answer is about LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 1):

`Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` have different rules for arithmetic. That is the only reason I can see for avoiding polymorphism for these two types. For example, adding *n* days to an `Instant` means adding *n times 86400* seconds to it. Always. That would not be the case if `ZonedDateTime` was a sub-class of `Instant`, because of rules for daylight savings time.

My understanding is that an `Instant` is similar to a `ZonedDateTime` with time zone `UTC`, so you could argue that `Instant` *is-a* `ZonedDateTime` instead. However, this would make `Instant` more complicated than it is today, since it would allow arithmetic with `TemporalUnit`s such as `MONTHS`. Arithmetic with *months* are time zone dependent, so `Instant` forces the programmer to select an explicit time zone before doing it.

Anyway, it is unfortunate that `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` aren't more compatible, since they both represent time unambiguously. It looks like they lack a common base class or interface without any methods for arithmetic.